# Use a bootstrap theme with blogdown

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap-3, hugo, blogdown

I currently have a website which was created using the rmarkdown default site generator. I used a bootstrap theme and I like the look of it and I am familiar with it. I am wanting to change the site over to a blogdown website, but do not want to change the look. I know it is possible to use a bootstrap theme with blogdown/hugo, but I have not found very much information on how this can be done. I am very new to website development, so my understanding is very basic. I do know that there is not just a simple answer to this. I am more looking for suggestions for how I should go about this, or resources that I might be able to use in order to accomplish this goal. If you are interested in seeing the site it is https://jamescuster.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anybody that is interested in this, I found this [blog](http://whipperstacker.com/2016/09/22/convert-an-existing-site-into-hugo/) post which helps turn any existing static website to hugo. I haven't completely gotten it all figured out, but it seems to working well so far and with a little tweaking I think I will be able to turn the bootstrap theme into a hugo theme.

I would still be interested to hear additional solutions.